# Notation for functions with vectors

Tags: functions, notation

Is there any common notation to write the following expression shorter?

$$
y_{1,t} = f(x_{1,t}; \vec{\theta_1}) \\
\vdots \\
y_{N,t} = f(x_{N,t}; \vec{\theta_N})
$$
$y$ and $x$ are both $NxT$ matrizes.
I thought of something like
$$
\vec{y} = f(\vec{x})
$$
But I think that could be misunderstood that for example $y_{2,t}$ is also a function of $x_{1,t}$. One could also think all the functions have the same parameters, although they differ. Only the function is the same.
However, that is another thing I want to write down:
$$
y_{1,t} = g(x_{1,t}, \cdots, x_{N,t}; \vec{\theta_i}) \\
\vdots \\
y_{N,t} = g(x_{1,t}, \cdots, x_{N,t}; \vec{\theta_N})
$$
How could I write this in shorter and in a notation to distinguish it from the expression above?

The reason I would like to do this is that I have all the rest of equations in fancy matrix notation and it would somehow be a shame to differ from that at this point.

Comment: The second one sure looks like $y=g(x)$ would be ok, I think. Put arrows over $x$ and $y$ if you really want to emphasize those are vectors. For the first one, does $(y_{1,t},\dots,y_{N.t})=(f(x_{1,t}),\dots,f(x_{N,t}))$ work for you?

Comment: For the first example, what I'd do is pull back $f$ to a map $f^*$, which simply applies $f$ coordinate-wise. Then, $y=f^*(x)$ would be unambiguous.

Comment: Ah, yes. I second Don's proposal. Every function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defines a new function $f^*:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ given coordinatewise. There is no standard notation for this exact case, I think, so $f^*$ looks good if you haven't used it for anything else.
But more generally, this is a special case of a pushforward, which is usually denoted $f_*$ by category theorists.

Comment: I needed to edit some parts, since I found I wasn't precise at some points. Would $y=g(x)$ still account for the different parameters of each function? Should I add a vector $\theta_i$ to make that obvious. For $y=g(x)$ then $\theta$ would be a $NxK$ matrix, where $K$ is constant over all rows (for example $K=2$ for g being affine.

Comment: I edited my post again to make the different function parameters more obvious. That's some notation I remembered from statistics classes. Sorry for changing it again. Regarding the mapping function: I don't really get, how I would express that $f*$ applies $f$ coordinate-wise. Just prose it? I am not a mathematician or maybe just too stupid right now to see the obvious.

Comment: Just say "I will use the symbol $f_*$ to denote the function defined by $f_*(a_1,\dots,a_n) = (f(a_1),\dots,f(a_n))$". That should work.

Comment: Now that you edited the post I don't really know what the $\theta$s stand for. Can you include an example?

Comment: I could use $f(x_{i,t}) = a_i + b_i x_{i,t}$ and it would be $\vec{\theta_i} = (a_i, b_i)$. With that notation I try to achieve that it is clear, that $f$ is always the same type of function, just with a different set of parameters depending on $i$. And I understand the $f_*$ thing now, thanks.